# 5 DIV Boxes - filling with color using querySelector and addEventListener

Tags: javascript, css, colors, onclick, addeventlistener

I had this on exam. I cant find a way to solve this problem

```
 <head>
    <style>
        div {
            border:1px solid black;
            display:inline-block;
            width: 150px;
            height:150px;
            margin-right: 50px;
        }
        .color {
            background-color:rgb(48, 241, 0);
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>

        <!-- script -->

        <script src='coloring.js'></script>
    </body>
```

What i need to do here is to use CSS class .color in JS and with a simple click to paint one of the DIV elements. After i click another DIV he paint in that green and on another it disapear. If you get me. I would love some tip or solution.
Help guys

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On clicking the `div`, first remove the class (`color`) from all `div`'s (if there is any). Then add the class (`color`) only to the clicked `div`. Try the following way by using [`Document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll):

```js
var div = document.querySelectorAll('div');
document.querySelectorAll('div').forEach(function(d){
  d.addEventListener('click', function(){
    div.forEach(function(el){
      el.classList.remove('color');
    })
    this.classList.add('color');
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  border:1px solid black;
  display:inline-block;
  width: 150px;
  height:150px;
  margin-right: 50px;
}
.color {
  background-color:green;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Get all the `div` and attach click event to them and inside the event handler get the div which has the class `color`. Use `classList.remove` to remove the color class from it,then use the `event` object to get the current target and use `classList.add` to add the `color` class

```js
let getDiv = document.querySelectorAll('div');
getDiv.forEach(function(item) {

  item.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    let getDivWithBcgColor = document.querySelector('.color');
    if (getDivWithBcgColor !== null) {
      getDivWithBcgColor.classList.remove('color')
    }
    e.target.classList.add('color')

  })


})
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin-right: 50px;
}

.color {
  background-color: rgb(48, 241, 0);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</body>
```